# UnityEditor Foldouts (Inventory System)

Tags: c#, serialization, unity-game-engine, inventory

I got a problem with my Inventory. I've made an Editor for the Inspector (To make the Inventory system more readable) with some Foldouts. I also have a constant Int which defines the number of my Inventory slots. The problem is that when I change the const int Tto lets say 6 I get multiple errors from the InventoryEditor class. When the const int is 4 or smaller everything works fine. But if I change the number to something higher I get errors like: IndexOutOfRangeException, NullReferenceException and so on (I put the exact logs underneath the question). The Inventory class should be fine I'm pretty sure the problem is in the InventoryEditor class.

Here's the Code:

```
public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour {

    public const int itemNumCap = 6;

    [SerializeField]
    private Item[] items = new Item[itemNumCap];

    [SerializeField]
    private Image[] itemsImg = new Image[itemNumCap];

    public void AddItem(Item itemToAdd)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
        {
            if (items[i] == null)
            {
                items[i] = itemToAdd;
                itemsImg[i].sprite = itemToAdd.sprite;
                itemsImg[i].enabled = true;

                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public void RemoveItem(Item itemToRemove)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
        {
            if (items[i] == itemToRemove)
            {
                items[i] = null;
                itemsImg[i].sprite = null;
                itemsImg[i].enabled = false;

                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And The InventoyEditor:

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(Inventory))]
public class InventoryEditor : Editor
{
    private bool[] showItemSlots = new bool[Inventory.itemNumCap];

    private SerializedProperty itemImagesProperty;
    private SerializedProperty itemsProperty;

    private const string inventoryPropItemImagesName = "itemsImg";
    private const string inventoryPropItemsName = "items";

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        itemImagesProperty = serializedObject.FindProperty(inventoryPropItemImagesName);
        itemsProperty = serializedObject.FindProperty(inventoryPropItemsName);
    }
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        serializedObject.Update();
        for (int i = 0; i < Inventory.itemNumCap; i++)
        {
            ItemSlotGUI(i);
        }
        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
    private void ItemSlotGUI(int index)
    {
        EditorGUILayout.BeginVertical(GUI.skin.box);
        EditorGUI.indentLevel++;

        showItemSlots[index] = EditorGUILayout.Foldout(showItemSlots[index], "Item slot " + index);
        if (showItemSlots[index])
        {
```

EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(itemImagesProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(index));

EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(itemsProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(index));

```
        }
        EditorGUI.indentLevel--;
        EditorGUILayout.EndVertical();
    }
}
```

I hope you guys could help me somehow.

Here are the error Logs:

```
IndexOutOfRangeException: Array Index is out of Range.
InventoryEditor.ItemSlotGUI (Int32 Index)

Retrieving Array Element thatw as out of bounds
UnityEditor.SerialziedProperty: GetArrayElementAtIndex (Int32)

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an Instance of an Object
UnityEditor.PropertyHandler.OnGUILayout(UnityEditor.SerializedProperty property, UnityEngine.GUIContent label, Boolean includeChildren, UnityEngine.GUILayoutOption[] options
```

And thats how it looks with 4 "Item Slots"[image: Inventory Component]

Comment: Technically the Array shouldnt be out of range because Its defined by the const Int "itemNumCap"

Comment: Have you tried using showItemSlots.Length in the loop? How many slots would that get you? Did you try a full rebuild? Maybe this is an issue of an inlined constant not getting replaced.

Comment: I believe this happens because when you change the `itemNumCap` value, you haven't (yet) reinitialized the arrays (which are fixed length, constructed during initialization of the class, prior to the constructor). So @OlivervanVelzen is wrong here.  Yes, the length of the arrays is defined by that integer, but they're only constructed once.

Comment: @Draco18s and how do I reinitialize the arrays ?

Comment: You would need to have `itemNumCap` have a getter/setter and you would need to call `new` on the arrays as well as copying over any existing content (if neccessary).

Comment: @Draco18s hmm let me try this

Comment: @Draco18s nope I added a getter, but I get still the same errors

Comment: You need a *setter* that creates new arrays: *`and you would need to call new on the arrays as well as copying over any existing content (if neccessary).`*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145883/discussion-between-oliver-van-velzen-and-draco18s).